# How to use case/esac in process substitution?

Tags: bash, shell, syntax, syntax-error, command-substitution

I've the following line which works fine:

```
while getopts :t t; do case $t in t) echo $t; break; esac; done
```

however when I'm trying to use it as command substitution, the bash fails with error.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo $BASH_VERSION
[ "$(while getopts :t t; do case $t in t) echo $t; break; esac; done)" = "t" ] && echo "Option specified."
```

Result:

```
$ ./test.sh -a -b -c -t
4.3.42(1)-release
./test.sh: line 3: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./test.sh: line 4: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Backslashing `\)` in `t)` doesn't help. And `(t)` syntax works in GNU bash 3.2.57, but it's not in 4.3.42.

It seems using backticks works fine for both versions:

```
[ "`while getopts :t t; do case $t in t) echo $t; break; esac; done`" = "t" ] && echo "Option specified."
```

however I don't want to use that syntax as it's [deprecated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/126927/21471).

**How I can use `case` syntax within the above command substitution (`$()`)?**

Or maybe there is other way of doing the same thing?

Basically to check whether `-t` parameter has been specified to the script and execute some command if so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a version of bash where the scanner was broken in such a way as to only terminate at an unbalanced `)` -- a bug which no longer exists in current 4.3 -- you could work around it as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
[ "$(while getopts :t t; do case $t in (t) echo $t; break;; esac; done)" = "t" ] && echo "Option specified."
```

The key difference here is using `(t)` rather than `t)`, thus resulting in parenthesis being balanced. This is [syntax explicitly allowed in the POSIX sh standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_04_05).

Comment: Are you sure you tested the first solution with 3.2.57? Only your second solution works for me on that version.

Comment: Your first line of your answer is incorrect - as per the link you provide at the end of your answer, "The ";;" is optional for the last compound-list."

Comment: Ooh; I'm using a `#!/usr/bin/env` shebang, which would put 4.3 first in my path; you're right, that's an error on my part.

Comment: If `;;` is optional for the last compound-list and when mixing `(t)` with `break;` (without `;;`), it still breaks on 4.3.42, but works on 3.2.57, does it mean my version is still buggy? It works however with `(t)` and `break;;`.

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to accomplish, though? The `[` ... `]` and the command substitution can most probably be avoided.  Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
while getopts :t t; do
  case $t in t) true; break;; *) false;; esac
done && echo Yes || echo No
```

The exit status of the `while` loop is the exit status of the `case` statement. There is no need to wrap that in `[` to examine whether it is true or not, which is frequently an antipattern anyway.