# Bash script has unexpected token `;;'

Tags: bash, switch-statement

I have a Bash command that is generated by a [buck](/questions/tagged/buck) Python script:

```
platform=$(case $(uname) in
  "Linux") echo "linux-x86_64" ;;
  "Darwin") echo "darwin64-x86_64-cc" ;;
  *) echo "Unknown" esac);
cp -r $SRCDIR $OUT && cd $OUT && ./Configure shared $platform --prefix=$OUT/build --openssldir=$OUT/build/openssl && make && make install
```

When I try to execute it, I get the following error:

> unexpected token `;;'

What have I done wrong here?

I am on the latest macOS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34502492/how-to-use-case-esac-in-process-substitution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closing `)` on the "Linux" case is terminating the process substitution.  Since it's bash, just use matching parens in the case:

```
platform=$(case $(uname) in
  ("Linux") echo "linux-x86_64" ;;
  ("Darwin") echo "darwin64-x86_64-cc" ;;
  (*) echo "Unknown";;
  esac
)
```

(Also, note that I had to add `;;` after the default case.)

Answer (score 4):

A much clearer and more efficient way to write the code would be:

```
case $(uname) in
  "Linux") platform="linux-x86_64" ;;
  "Darwin") platform="darwin64-x86_64-cc" ;;
  *) platform="Unknown" ;;
esac
```

Having the result of `echo` captured by `$()` is something of a shell anti-pattern.  Why write to stdout and read from stdin when you can simply use the text directly?

Comment: I am debating down voting or deleting my own answer!  Not sure deleting is right, since the mismatched closing paren could be a common source of error, but this solution is far more appropriate for this case.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like:

```
get_platform() {
        case "${1,,}" in
                darwin*) echo darwin64...  ;;
                freebsd*) echo freebsd...  ;;
                linux*) echo linux-x86_64.. ;;
                cygwin*) echo cyg...  ;;
                *) return 1;;
        esac
        return 0
}

platform=$(get_platform "$OSTYPE" || get_platform $(uname))
echo "${platform:-Unknown}"
```

Double check - `bash` stores the operating system in the `$OSTYPE` variable. In case of fail (other shells), it still trying to use the `uname`.

In the case of undetected OS, the final decision, is populated to the main script (`return 1`) so you can check and adjust it as you want, like `echo "${platform:-Unknown}"`.